# Can 3 replicas use the same PersistentVolume in a StatefulSet in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset, persistent-volume-claims, gce-persistent-disk

I created a StatefulSet for running my NodeJS with 3 replicas and want to attach to a gce disk that can become a data storage for user to upload files.

My project naming: carx; Server name: car-server

**However I got an error while creating the second pod.**

```
kubectl describe pod car-server-statefulset-1
```

> AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "my-app-data" : googleapi: Error
> 400: RESOURCE_IN_USE_BY_ANOTHER_RESOURCE - The disk resource
> 'projects/.../disks/carx-disk' is already being used by
> 'projects/.../instances/gke-cluster-...-2dw1'

---

**car-server-statefulset.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: car-server-service
  labels:
    app: car-server
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: car-server
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: car-server
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: car-server-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: "car-server-service"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: car-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: car-server
          image: myimage:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: nodejs-port
          volumeMounts:
          - name: my-app-data
            mountPath: /usr/src/app/mydata
      volumes:
      - name: my-app-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: example-local-claim
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: car-server
```

---

**pvc.yml**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-local-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: standard
```

---

**pv.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-app-data
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 60Gi
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: carx-disk
    fsType: ext4
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Access Mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) field is treated as a *request*, but it is not sure that you get what you requests. In your case, [GCEPersistentDisk](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) only support `ReadWriteOnce` or `ReadOnlyMany`.

Your PV is now mounted as `ReadWriteOnce` but can only be mounted on **one** node at the same time. So the other replicas will fail to mount the volume.

When using [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/), it is common that each replica use its own volume, use the `volumeClaimTemplate:` part of the `StatefulSet` manifest for that.

Example:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: example-claim
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "standard"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

In case that you only can use a single volume, you may consider to run the `StatefulSet` with only one replica, e.g. `replicas: 1`.

If you want disk-replication, you can use a *StorageClass* for *regional disks* that are replicated to another AZ as well. See [Regional Persistent Disk](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/regional-pd), but it still have the same *access modes*.

Comment: Thanks for reply! if each replica use its own volume, the data file in those volumes will not be synchronized automatically? I required set another configuration to do that?

Comment: @potato, yes that is true. Use only 1 replica if your app does not replicate the data.

Comment: So that's means I cannot configure 3 replicas to share the data file on one PV in GCE? because I want my app being scalable. So is this a right way to make each replica use its own volume and synchronize data between volumes for a scalable app?

Comment: @potato it is much easier to do the server scalable if it does not use a volume, e.g. use a `Deployment` without volume. Maybe you can use a GCS bucket or a database for the things that you want to use a volume for instead?

Comment: My app is going to allow users to upload files with 1MB each, so I would like to use disk storage like storing images. I will look over GCS bucket whether is suitable for me. Well thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk)

> A feature of PD is that they can be mounted as read-only by multiple
> consumers simultaneously. This means that you can pre-populate a PD
> with your dataset and then serve it in parallel from as many Pods as
> you need. Unfortunately, PDs can only be mounted by a single consumer
> in read-write mode - no simultaneous writers allowed.

Alternative solution is Google Cloud Filestore which is a NAS offering. You can mount the Filestore in Compute Engine and Kubernetes Engine instances. However, the problem with Filestore is that it designed with large file storage systems in mind and has minimum capacity of 1TB which is expensive for small use cases.

An inexpensive way to solve the issue is to setup a NFS server in your cluster backed up by a ReadWriteOnce PV and then create NFS based PV (which supports ReadWriteMany) using this NFS server